# Embed in guildCreate (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Hello I programming my discord.js and I don't know how to make embed in guildCreate. I have this:

```
client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
  if (guild.systemChannel)
    guild.systemChannel.send('witamy');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function really doesn't matter, you can create a embed anywhere.

```
client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
  if (guild.systemChannel) {
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("This is a embed!")
    .setDescription("And this is the description!");
    guild.systemChannel.send(embed);
  }
});
```